# Is there any issue with using a StopWatch around Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, wpf, stopwatch, parallel.foreach

I am using this logic in a WPF application. I am seeing the execution done in 3seconds visually (from the database), but for some reason the stop watch prints out 17s or more.

The code within the Parallel.For block does a lot of calculations and writes to db. So by visually, I mean from the database select query.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            // Begin timing
            stopwatch.Start();

            String currentTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
            statusLabel.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                 new Action(delegate() { statusLabel.Content = "New Minute data processing..." + currentTime; }));


            int size = NumSymWatching;


            Parallel.For(0, size, x =>
             {
               CalculateStudies(SymbolsToWatch[x], SymbolSessions[x]);
              });



            UpdateApplicationStatusTable();
            stopwatch.Stop();

            statusLabel.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                 new Action(delegate() { lblTimer.Content = "Time taken to run: " + stopwatch.Elapsed; }));
            isRunning = false;
```

**EDIT**
After a few tests, I've found that there is no issue with using stopwatch around a Parallel.For loop.

Comment: What does `UpdateApplicationStatusTable` do?

Comment: If you replace the `Parallel` call with a standard loop does the execution time increase? I don't think there is anything wrong with the stopwatch.

Comment: UpdateApplicationStatusTable() updates a row in the db. That table just has 3 rows.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson - Trying that now

Comment: @QuintinRobinson - 

Crap.. I am seeing mixed results. First Parallel.For was slower. Now it's faster. 

By *it I mean the timer

Comment: I guess I need more testing.
Here's the thing-
The UI thread is the main thread. Stop Watch is on that thread. Parallel.For spawns other threads. I believe the Parallel.For loop completes before the code execution reaches the next line.
Now we get hold of the main UI thread and update it. I don't see anything wrong with the stop watch logic.

Comment: Test with more items. With more items, I see timer way off while using Parallel.For

Comment: After more testing there is nothing wrong with the code. Stopwatch is correct.

Comment: @TejaswiRana In that case, I think you should delete this question.